# Example of noncommutative ring in which all nonzero elements are invertible

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

> Example of noncommutative ring in which all nonzero elements are
>   invertible.

I was thinking along Matrices in $(2,\mathbb Z$), but some nonzero matrices are not invertible.

Can someone provide me with an example?

Comment: Hamilton's Quaternions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion

Comment: You can indeed "think along matrices", too, by representing the quaternion algebra by complex $2\times 2$ matrices.